# Upgrade 17.10 - 18.04 wayland default, xorg freezes

Tags: nvidia, xorg, crash, gdm, 18.04

I had installed Ubuntu 17.10 with xorg as default display driver. I had nvidia-384 drivers and everything worked, no issues.

I have upgraded the system today from 17.10 to find out that my default session is wayland on Nouveau drivers. I tried to switch to xorg but the screen freezes and I can't login. If I install latest nvidia-390 drivers and try to login with wayland it ends up in a endless Start job has been started and I can't get to gdm login screen.If I use it with open source drivers everything is choppy and doesn't work well.

Any ideas why xorg is not default like it suppose to be, and why I can't run GDM with xorg?

Answer (score 0):

There currently seems to be [many problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1752053) with nVidia drivers in Ubuntu, perhaps due to bugs on nVidia's side.  Perhaps this will take some time to stabilize.  For now, I reverted to nouveau open source drivers, I removed the previous manual /etc/X11/xorg.conf that was pointing at nvidia, and finally I had my i3 window manager again.